# Adding a row to a tableView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableView` I'm trying to add a row to the `tableView`. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger indexPath = [self.rowArray count] - 1;

    // I'm adding an object to an array of all the cell ids I have.
    [self.rowArray insertObject:@"rowSix" atIndex:indexPath];  // rowSix is a cell ID

    [self.myTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.myTableView endUpdates];

}
```

This is the error that it outputs:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

**Update**

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSString *cellID = [self.rowArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: If you have an array of cell id's, you're probably doing something wrong. You generally only have one id for each cell type. Do you have multiple cell types (different subclasses)?

Comment: use [self.myTableView reloadData]; method instead of `[self.myTableView beginUpdates];   [self.myTableView endUpdates];`

Comment: @rdelmar I have different cell prototypes.

Comment: @SumitGarg That doesn't animate the tableView

Comment: Just updated question

Answer (score 1):

Try this one-

```
//Update data source with the object that you need to add
[tableDataSource addObject:newObject];

NSInteger row = //specify a row where you need to add new row
NSInteger section = //specify the section where the new row to be added, 

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
    - (IBAction)addRow:(id)sender
    {
        [self.rowArray addObject:@"New Item"];
        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.rowArray count] inSection:0];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
```

Comment: now you used insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation Method between `[self.myTableView beginUpdates];   [self.myTableView endUpdates];`

Comment: When I do that, it makes other cells smaller. Not sure why

Comment: Just did that. It animates and everything, but the problem is, it make other cells smaller.